# Using webapp2.uri_for in Django template

Tags: google-app-engine, django-templates, webapp2

I have a GAE app that's using the stock webapp2 framework and Django templating engine. This setup doesn't seem to support Django's builtin {% url %} template tag.

Rather than hard-code URLs into my templates, I'd like to use the webapp2.uri_for function within my templates. Is this possible? If so, how might I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try writing a custom template tag, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags

You might have a look at the source code of the Django tag at
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaulttags.py#L1194

Comment: webapp2 doesn't support custom Django tags, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. I had the same question today and ended up with the following template tag. I wanted the functionality to support the django "as" syntax so that was brought over from the django url template tag.

```
from django import template
import webapp2

register = template.Library()


def uri_for(parser, token):
    """Webapp2 uri_for django template tag"""
    bits = token.split_contents()
    if len(bits) < 2:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("'%s' takes at least one argument (path to a view)" % bits[0])

    view_name = bits[1]
    as_var = None
    if len(bits) >= 2 and bits[-2] == 'as':
        as_var = bits[-1]

    return UriForNode(view_name, as_var)
uri_for = register.tag(uri_for)


class UriForNode(template.Node):
    """Uri for node"""
    def __init__(self, uri, as_var=None):
        self.uri = uri
        self.as_var = as_var

    def render(self, context):
        view = webapp2.uri_for(self.uri)
        if self.as_var:
            context[self.as_var] = view
            return ''
        return view
```